# Enumerate tables in iSeries DB2 from C#/ODBC

Tags: c#, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I need to enumerate all tables (by that I mean get a list of schema and table name strings) and views in an iSeries DB2 database (I believe version 7, but I could be wrong) for which I have an ODBC connection. I tried:

```
show tables
select * from syscat.tables
```

However, the server responds with unknown command for `show tables` and unknown table for select respectively:

> ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - TABLES in SYSCAT type *FILE not found

I know that it is somehow possible to enumerate tables because Visual Studio does it from the Server Explorer. I am probably overlooking something very obvious but I am not really versed in ODBC. Thanks.

Comment: "enumerate" how?  The **contents** of `syscat.tables` is a whole bunch of info, including name.  Without looking at the documentation, I'm guessing you can't use an SQL statement as a parameter for `show tables` (assuming that's a valid command, which I'd have to check).    Or, you'd have to specify which column has the table/schema name (no way you can use `SELECT *`.  Why do you want to enumerate all tables anyways?  Why is looking it up via Server Explorer not sufficient?

Comment: Database is huge, it has over 3000 tables, and I need to provide a report which of them have any data in them. I can easily do a `count(*)` on tables, but for that I need a list of table names.

Comment: Btw, there is no `syscat.tables` table. trying to do a select on it returns `ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - TABLES in SYSCAT type *FILE not found`

Comment: hmm, seems I've now forgotten everything is prefixed.  Incidentally, if the tables are in regular i5/OS land [SYSTABLESTAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzcatsyststat.htm?lang=en) has row counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzcatsqltables.htm?lang=en), you probably want to use something like

```
select table_name from sysibm.sqltables
```

Comment: OK, works, and you answered first, so I'll accept your answer. Though I found a way VS does it, there is a `GetSchema` method on `OdbcConnection` object, which returns details on specific parts of schema. E.g. calling `conn.GetSchema("Tables");` returns what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

To get table names try
select * from QSYS2.SYSTABLES

Comment: This is not a bad answer, and it *should* work. But the SYSIBM library (a.k.a. schema) is explicitly for ODBC and JDBC catalog views. The QSYS2 library is for DB2 for i, ANS, and ISO catalog views. I guess the idea is that the latter may or may not be supported by your ODBC client. I happen to use the QSYS2 stuff myself when I connect using the ODBC driver that comes with Client Access (or iSeries Access, or IBM i Access) for Windows.

Comment: Actually it does work, so does sysibm, but @mustaccio answered first, so I'll accept his answer.